# Microsoft Access search query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a search query that compare the text from text box with my database table untill now I have no problem and every thing works good .. but when I want to make the query compare part of text with database here I have the problem. For example if I have record "USA". I want to type "us" in the text box the query must have a result "USA".

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Goods.ID, Goods.Name, Goods.Description,
       Goods.CatID, Goods.SubCatId, Goods.DealerPrice,
       Goods.SuperDealerPrice, Goods.EndUserPrice,
       Goods.BarCode, Goods.Quantity
FROM Goods 
WHERE (((Goods.CatID)=Forms!Form1!Text58)
       And ((Forms!Form1!Text78) Is Null))
       Or (((Goods.SubCatId)=Forms!Form1!Text78))
       Or (((Goods.BarCode)=Forms!Form1!Text115))
       Or (((Goods.Name)= Forms!Form1!Text115))
       Or ((Goods.Description) Like [Forms]![Form1]![Text115]);
```

I know in sql I must to put "%" in the query but it's not work.
Can any one show me how to make the change on this code here and I will make the others:

```
((Goods.Description) Like [Forms]![Form1]![Text115]);
```

Comment: Show how you tried to add the `%` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*` in Access.

```
((Goods.Description) Like "*" & [Forms]![Form1]![Text115] & "*")
```

Or you can use `alike` if you plan to use `%`.

```
((Goods.Description) alike "%" & [Forms]![Form1]![Text115] & "%")
```

Comment: it's not working i have a syntax error i am not working on events i am working on query design

Comment: try this. access uses `double quotes`.

Comment: ok now its work .. thank u alot .. and it will be very good if u told me how to make it search by at least 2 char .. for example if i type "a" i didn't wont any result .. if i type "ai" i want it to retrive data like air .. airplane.. airbag..

Comment: you would use `a*` for words starting with `a`. `ai*` for words starting with `ai`